# Unmarshalling a json in multiple structs in Go

Tags: json, go, struct, interface

I have a case where I have to parse a long json in multiple structs. An example is:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Instance []Instance `json:"instance"`
}
type Test1 struct {
        Envid   string `json:"envid"`
        Narid   string `json:"narid"`
        Pod     []Pod  `json:"pod"`
        Regions string `json:"regions"`
        Type    string `json:"type"`
}
type JavaTest struct {
    JavaOutput     string `json:"java output"`
    JvmVersion     string `json:"jvm_version"`
}
type Container struct {
    Java []Java `json:"java"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
type Pod struct {
    Container []Container `json:"container"`
    Name      string      `json:"name"`
}

type Instance struct {
        Test1 Test1 `json:"test1,omitempty"`
        Test2 Test2 `json:"test2,omitempty"`
}
```

While Unmarshalling the JSON, I am not exactly sure how it should be done. If I do: `var test AutoGenerated` and use this to unmarshal, I miss out on fields from `JavaTest` struct like `JvmVersion`. Is there any way I get fill values in different structs from a single JSON? Note that I have a lot of different structs like this.

Sample json snippet:

```
{
  "instance": [
    {
      "test1": {
        "envid": "test1",
        "narid": "",
        "pod": [
          {
            "container": [
              {
                "java": [
                  {
                    "java output": "asdsadasdasdasd",
                    "jvm_version": "1.8.0_152",
                    "path": "/abc/aa/11/80/aaaaaa/bbb/aaa",
                    "publisher": "Java asdsad"
                  }
                ],
                "name": "test"
              }
            ],
            "name": "test-2-6n8xc"
          }
        ],
        "regions": "abc",
        "type": "xyz"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you can cherry pick only the fields you care about when defining your structs

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: The JSON structure looks like this - 
obj.instance[7]["ab1111-a"].pod[1].container[0].java[0].jvm_version.

The `obj.instance[]` is an array within which I have `["ab1111-a"]`.

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande: that's not JSON. Can you paste a valid small JSON sample in *your question*, properly formatted? Also, please check if http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/go-json-cookbook/ helps you get a better idea of how JSON can be handled in Go

Comment: @EliBendersky Added the json snippet to the question.

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande can you show how the `Instance` type is defined?

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande See if this is what you're looking for: https://play.golang.org/p/4hk55odEfPP

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande note in your updated question the `Instance`'s `test1` and `test2` fields are *unexported*, that's a problem, unmarshal won't see those.

Comment: @mkopriva I see. Looking at this - https://play.golang.org/p/4hk55odEfPP, this might solve the issue. Let me give this a go.

Comment: @mkopriva I have modified the structs now, `test1` should have been `Test1`.

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande and does it not work? It works for me: https://play.golang.org/p/U_VzUTqQytk

Comment: Not exactly. It complains that Instance does not have a field or method with the name Pod.

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande Well that's correct since *you* defined Instance as having only two fields Test1 and Test2, why would you try to access the Pod field directly through Instance and not through one of its Test fields?

Comment: @mkopriva That's right. So, I tried to access the Instance specific details by: `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", testInst.Instance[0])` where `var testInst AutoGenerated`. This worked. 

I also tried doing a range loop on `testInst.Instance` which worked. It looped over all the test instances and returned their details. The only thing I noticed is that when the `Test2` data is returned with values, `Test1`'s fields are also returned without values, which I think is expected, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is expected, those are called [zero values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value). If you want you could define the Test fields as pointer fields, i.e. `Instance struct { Test1 *Test1 ... }` and then after unmarshaling check the fields against `nil` before accessing any of their fields. This will work because the "zero value" of pointer types is `nil`, while the "zero value" of struct types is a struct value with all its fields set to their respective "zero value".

Comment: @mkopriva I know this is not related to the original question, but, can you, by any chance give an idea of how I can iterate over all fields of `Instance` struct without explicitly mentioning the field names? For example, doing a range on `AutoGenerated.Instance` which will loop through Test1,Test2, etc.? Right now what I am doing is looping over `AutoGenerated.Instance.Test1` which isn't ideal for too many fields in Instance struct.

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande it's not possible to loop through a struct's fields, not without reflection which is undesirable. What you could do however is to use a map like I've demonstrated in my first example on playground, then you can loop over the map to get the keys and values. Here's the mentioned example with a loop for clarification: https://play.golang.org/p/MoMDZ4OCClA

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks. I will try this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to modify the struct definition. Below changes were made:

1. Modify `AutoGenerated` struct to:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Instance []map[string]Instance `json:"instance"`
}
```

2. Modify `Instance` struct to:

```
type Instance struct {
        Envid string `json:"envid"`
        Narid string `json:"narid"`
        Pod   []Pod  `json:"pod"`

}
```

Please read the discussion in the comment as to understand why these changes were made. Basically, I wanted to loop over the fields of `Instance` struct which was only possible via reflect (a less desirable solution). So, a solution to the correct parsing of this json was suggested in the comments by using map for the Instance.

I also completely removed individual structs for Instance fields like `Test1`, `Test2`, etc.

Thanks to everyone who helped me resolve this issue.